# Retorno de dos valores en JAVA

Tags: java, java-8

estoy trabajando en un conversor de decimal a binario y viceversa todo esto debe ir dentro de un mismo método el problema es que no se como retornar el valor del binario y el del decimal dejo el código esperando un poco de ayuda

```
package numerosBinariosYDecimales;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinariosYDecimales {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Scanner lecturaDatos = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa un numero decimal");
        long decimal =lecturaDatos.nextLong();
        long auxiliar = decimal;
        String binario="";

        while (auxiliar >0){
            binario = auxiliar %2 + binario;
            auxiliar /=2;

        }
        System.out.println("El numero decimal "+decimal+" en binario es: "+binario);

        //conversion de binario a decimal

        long numBinario = Long.parseLong(binario);
        long numDecimal=0;
        int contador =1;
        long auxiliarDecimal;
        while (numBinario >0){
            auxiliarDecimal = numBinario %2;
            numDecimal = numDecimal + auxiliarDecimal * contador;
            numBinario /=10;
            contador = contador*2;

        }
        System.out.println("El numero binario "+binario+" es "+decimal+" en numeros decimales");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes retornar un arreglo de dos elementos, en una posición guardas el valor decimal y en la otra el binario.

Answer (score 2):

Me he encontrado este caso las suficientes veces como para hacer una pequeña clase que permita agrupar dos valores. Aquí está:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public final class Pair<L, R> {

    private L left;
    private R right;

    public Pair(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    // permite crear una Pair sin especificar los tipos, asi: Pair.of("hola", 654)
    public static <L, R> Pair<L, R> of(L left, R right) {
        return new Pair<>(left, right);
    }

    public L getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public Pair<L, R> setLeft(L left) {
        return new Pair<>(left, right);
    }

    public <T> Pair<T, R> updateLeft(T left) {
        return new Pair<>(left, right);
    }

    public R getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public Pair<L, R> setRight(R right) {
        return new Pair<>(left, right);
    }

    public <T> Pair<L, T> updateRight(T right) {
        return new Pair<>(left, right);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + left + ", " + right + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) o;
        return Objects.equals(left, pair.left) &&
                Objects.equals(right, pair.right);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(left, right);
    }
}
```

Y su uso en tu caso:

```
int binario = 0;
int decimal = 0;

// aqui tu logica

return Pair.of(binario, decimal);

// y en otro punto del programa

int a = numeros.getLeft();
int b = numeros.getRight();

System.out.println(numeros);    // imprime (0, 0)
```

---

#### Disclaimer

Es cierto que estos tipos de estructuras están implementados de una manera u otra en muchas librerías, como la de [Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) o [Vavr](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.1/io/vavr/Tuple2.html), pero hay veces que solo necesitas esta funcionalidad y usar una librería es demasiado.