# Recorrer lista de listas streams JAVA8

Tags: lista, java-8

Tengo las siguientes 2 clases A y B, donde el objeto A tiene una lista de objetos B

```
class A {
   Collection<B> listB ;
   String x;
   // Some other variables
}

class B {
   String y;
   // Some other variables
}
```

Tengo una lista de listas, cada objeto A tiene una lista de B

```
Collection<class A> listA;
```

Para recorrerlas realicé el siguiente código. pero recorriendo la lista del objeto B, pierdo la referencia del objeto A:

```
listA.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getListaB() != null)
    .flatMap(a -> a.getListB().stream())
    .forEach(b -> {
                // Aquí pierdo la referencia del objeto
                // Necesito algo como a.getX()
                // Utilizando también la lista b algo como b.getY()
                    });
```

Hay alguna solución para no perder la referencia del objeto A utilizando preferiblemente streams y NO forEach ni for loop????

Comment: en ve de flatMap usa map, así harás algo para cada lista interna en vez de para cada lista interna convertida a stream. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684562/whats-the-difference-between-map-and-flatmap-methods-in-java-8

Comment: Pero cuando realizo el forEach pierdo la referencia de la lista a, porque estoy recorriendo la lista b, ya edité el código en la pregunta para ver si es más claro. Muchas gracias

Comment: por favor agrega unos datos de ejemplo y algo como qué esperas que salga. procura siempre poner un [mcve]

Comment: ¿Y por qué no crear una clase que agrupe ambos tipos y mapear? Escribí una implementación en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183493/57827). Sería cuestión de mapear así: `.map (a -> Pair.of(a, a.getListB())` y ya tienes ambas referencias, aunque por supuesto te será más engorroso operar con el stream.